# Semaphore semget method return value confirmation

Tags: c, linux, semaphore

I want to get a same `semId` using same key.
Although, I called `semget` method using same key, and returned different `semId`.

Please answer me the reason why this problem happened.

**Sample source :**

```
int id1, id2;
int semflg = IPC_CREAT | 0666;
id1 = semget(0, 1, semflg);
id2 = semget(0, 1, semflg);
```

Result : id1 != id2

Comment: I think you need to add some tags to this question, since `semget` is not part of the C language.

Comment: @shlim what are the value of `id1` and `id2`? Did you checked that none is having value `-1`?

Comment: id1, id2 value is some value which registed in IPC semaphore
for example id1 = 786432, id2 = 819201

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key id `0` is `IPC_PRIVATE`, and will always generate a new set of semaphores. Choose a valid key.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think that IPC_PRIVATE was 0.
T.T